# Installing JSON Gem with Bundler without GCC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, json, rubygems, bundler

I am in the process of deploying a rails application to a server. There are a few environmental limitations, namely:

1. No internet access on server
2. No root access on server
3. No build tools (GCC, etc)

I almost have the capistrano deployment working, however I get a failure when bundler tries to install the json gem:

```
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] 
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] /app/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] creating Makefile
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] 
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] make
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] compiling generator.c
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] make: gcc: Command not found
** [out :: 192.168.7.115] make: *** [generator.o] Error 127
```

Since there is no internet, I have all of my gems stored in `vendor/cache`. I wanted to solve this problem by compiling the json gem on a similar machine that *does* have gcc, but I wasn't able to find a "compiled-looking" gem on the system. Normally, I see a `[gemname]-x86_64-linux.gem` gemfile that indicates the compilation has already been taken care of. Can't seem to find this for the JSON gem, but if I did, I'm guessing I could just drop it in my `vendor/cache` folder and call it a day.

Any suggestions? Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend this method as it's likely a **bad thing** on many levels, but it did solve my problem. I ended up copying the `shared/bundle` folder from the staging server to the production server. Bundler sees that the gems are already installed and doesn't try to reinstall them.